# Not able to collect data from all custom cells in table view

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, ios8, uisegmentedcontrol

In my program, I have created a table view with my own custom table view cell that has segmented control objects on each one. I want to be able to iterate through these cells (not visible cells because they are being created as the program is being loaded) and see which option of the segmented control that the user chose. I want to then put that data in an array and do stuff with it. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Why not just create a dictionary and when the user selects a segmented control option, record the value in the dictionary. User selects segmented control -> [yourDictionary setObject:@"selectedOption" forKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:rowNumberThatUserTapped"]];

Comment: If the user doesn't touch the segmented control (implicitly selecting the default option), this will not be registered because the user never pressed the segmented control.

Answer (score 1):

This is not the way to think of the problem. Reading back from the cells with a loop is impossible because some the cells get dequeued as you scroll through the UITableView.

First you have to create an array containing the rowCount items with the default selected option at start time.

```
var options:Array<Int> = Array(count: rowCount, repeatedValue: 0)
```

Then inside the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` you set the segmented control value from the `options` Array. Also you set the tag as indexPath.row to identify the row later.

```
cell.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = options[indexPath.row]
cell.segmentedControl.tag = indexPath.row
```

Then in segmentedControl `ValueChanged` event set the options array to the selected value in the segmented control

```
func onValueChanged(sender : UISegmentedControl) {
    options[sender.tag] = sender.selectedSegmentIndex
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This works for integers. Now in my case, I want to retrieve the titles (strings) that belong in the segmented control so I have to make my options array a string array and change a few lines. For some reason, this is not working as easily as I thought.

Comment: how do u set the options string array to the segmented control? You have a datasource right? Can't you read it  back from the datasource using the `selectedSegmentIndex`